# Is it bad practice not combining independent observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, combinations

So, I have three independent observables:

```
ngOnInit(){
    first$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
    second$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
    third$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
}
```

Is it bad practice not combining the observables above? I am new to RxJS and there are a lot of combination operators like `combineLatest` which I would use but in this case I only want to `console.log` new values:

```
ngOnInit(){
    combineLatest([first$,second$,third$]).subscribe(([firstVal, secondVal, thirdVal]) => {
        console.log([firstVal, secondVal, thirdVal]);
    })
}
```

The problem here would be that only one of the three observables has to emit a new value to execute the body but then also old values are logged in the console.

So the best way would be to handle them separately but then I wonder: Is it bad practice not combining independent observables since the RxJS library has a lot of combination operators?

Comment: The question should be "when we use Rxjs to join observables?". If you need at first on your app get values from two APIs -e.g. a serie of employeds and qualification- you should use `forkJoin`, if you need get a region based in the parameters of your app, you should use `switchMap`, If you need make the same action when a click or keyboard enter you use `merge`. If you has two independent observables with no relations and you need make a diferent action -e.g. you want control if a FormControl value change and a personal Subject when you resize the screen-, has no sense combine the observables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not bad practice. The combination operators are only meant for exactly the scenario where it makes sense to combine the observables. If your observables are independent from each other, it would actually be bad practice to combine them, for exactly the reason you mentioned:

> The problem here would be that only one of the three observables has to emit a new value to execute the body but then also old values are logged in the console.

If you check the [rxjs documentation for combination operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination) you actually find a description and how to use each combination operator. It should become clear, for what use case they are meant.

Answer (score 0):

Is it bad practice not combining independent observables? Maybe, but certainly not always.

In your case, you're just logging the output of three streams. What you've written can be refactored from

```
first$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
second$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
third$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

to

```
merge(first$, second$, third$).subscribe(console.log);
```

These two things should always have the same output. Is one better than the other? Well, the second approach has a bit less boilerplate code. If the consumer of all three streams doesn't really care about the source of a value, acting on a merged stream rather than subscribing to each stream individually is more concise.

On the other hand, if your consumer cares about the source of a value (Did this value come from the `first$` or `third$`?), then merging seems like a bad idea.

```
car$.subscribe(car => console.log(car.wheel.pressure));
plane$.subscribe(plane => console.log(plane.wings));
train$.subscribe(_ => console.log("CHOO CHOO!"));

merge(car$, plane$, train$).subscribe(val => {
  if(val instanceof Car) console.log(val.wheel.pressure);
  else if(val instanceof Plane) console.log(val.wings);
  else if(val instanceof Train) console.log("CHOO CHOO!");
  else console.err(val);
});
```

This is a bit of an antipattern. You're merging three streams, but then you're doing the work of separating them again. The approach of subscribing separately seems clearer here.

Generally, merging streams should add some semantic value. It should be a hint to anybody reading your code that the combined streams are somehow related. That they're **meant/designed** to be consumed uniformly or that a consumer needs values from both (ect).